# Use this java code on Xamarin

Tags: java, c#, xamarin

How can i use this java code on xamarin?

```
  ContentResolver cr = context.getContentResolver();
        int set = android.provider.Settings.System.WIFI_SLEEP_POLICY_NEVER;
        android.provider.Settings.System.putInt(cr, android.provider.Settings.System.WIFI_SLEEP_POLICY, set);
```

I'm trying something like this but i'm getting error Cannot convert wifi policy to int.

```
  ContentResolver cr = ContentResolver;
        int set = Android.Provider.Settings.System.WifiSleepPolicyNever;
        Android.Provider.Settings.System.PutInt(cr, Android.Provider.Settings.System.WifiSleepPolicy, set);
```

Comment: if that's C#, and WifiSleepPolicyNever is an enum, you just need an explicit cast in there like int set = (int)Android.Provider.Settings.System.WifiSleepPolicyNever;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cast your Enum with int to solve the issue.

```
int set = (int)Android.Provider.Settings.System.WifiSleepPolicyNever;
```

But `Android.Provider.Settings.System.WifiSleepPolicyNever` is no more usable & will be removed in future version, this class is deprecated instead you should use the code below

```
var cr = ContentResolver;
int set= (int)Android.Provider.WifiSleepPolicy.Never;
Android.Provider.Settings.System.PutInt(cr, Android.Provider.Settings.System.WifiSleepPolicy, set);
```